# If a self-adjoint operator has a mixed spectrum, is it necessarily bounded from below?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $A:\mathcal{D}(A)\subsetneq\mathscr{H} \rightarrow \mathscr{H}$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator in a complex separable Hilbert space. Let $\sigma_{\text{pp}}(A)\neq \emptyset$ and $\sigma_{\text{c}}(A)\neq\emptyset$. Does it follow that $\sigma (A)= \sigma_{\text{pp}}(A)\cup \sigma_{\text{c}}(A)$ has a lower bound? How can one show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that if $A$ satisfies this condition, then so does $-A$. If your assertion were true, this would imply that $A$ and $-A$ are lower bounded, in other words, $A$ would have to be bounded. But that is of course not true.

For an explicit counterexample take $\mathscr H=L^2(\mathbb R,\lambda|_{[0,1]}+\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\delta_k)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $A$ the operator of multiplication by the identity function. Then $\sigma_c(A)=[0,1]$, $\sigma_{pp}(A)=\mathbb Z\setminus \{0,1\}$, yet $A$ is clearly not bounded or semi-bounded.

Comment: Can you explain the notation inside the bracket, please?

Comment: I'd guess it's the sum of the restriction of Lebesgue measure to the unit interval, i.e. $\lambda|_{[0,1]}(E) := \lambda(E \cap [0,1])$; and the [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) a.k.a. the Sha function (named for its similarity to the Cyrillic letter Ш).

Comment: @DanielC It's what kahen says. You take a continuous measure and add a discrete measure. The continuous measure gives you continuous spectrum and the discrete measure gives you discrete spectrum.

Comment: @MaoWao But what if I impose that $\mathscr{H} = L^2 (\mathbb R, dx)$, i.e. I do not "atomize" the measure? I necessarily obtain that $A$ be bounded? That can't be true. Think of the Hydrogen atom's Hamiltonian, it's unbounded with a "ground state" the "left side" of the pure point spectrum.

Comment: Of course what I wrote about the correspondence between measure and spectrum only holds for the operator of multiplication by the identity function. Since your and my Hilbert space are isomorphic, you can transfer this example also to your Hilbert space, just that the operator will no longer be multiplication by the identity.